# Are inner product equations invariant everywhere in spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, covariance

For example, in Minkowski space, the energy of a massive particle is given by
$$E=-P_{\mu}U^{\mu},$$
where the sign depends on the metric convention, $P$ is the particle 4-momentum and $U$ is the 4-momentum of the observer measuring the energy. Now, this holds in arbitrary coordinates because it is a tensor equation, but does the equation hold with arbitrary curvature? At any random, arbitrary point in spacetime, will an observer with 4-velocity $U$ measure the energy of a particle with 4-momentum $P$ to be $-P_{\mu}U^{\mu}$?

In general, we know that if I write some tensor equation, it will hold for all coordinate systems, but the equation will not necessarily hold at any arbitrary point on the spacetime manifold. For example, $R_{\mu\nu}=0$ may hold true in some regions of spacetime but not in others, where $R_{\mu\nu}$ is the Ricci tensor. Does this same logic hold for inner products, or are inner product equations invariant across a manifold as well as between coordinate systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At any random, arbitrary point in spacetime, will an observer with 4-velocity $U$ measure the energy of the particle with 4-momentum $P$ to be $-P_{\mu}U^{\mu}$?

If you mean that if the same expression applies to any spacetime point, then the answer is more or less. The equation applies only at the intersection points between the path of the particle and the path of the observer.

First of all, the metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$ is a function of the point $p$ of spacetime, that is $g_{\mu\nu}=g_{\mu\nu}(p)$, and the same happens with the components of $E$ and $U$, that is, $E^{\mu}=E^{\mu}(p)$, $U^{\mu}=U^{\mu}(p)$, but  $U^{\mu}$ is only defined along the geodesic followed by the observer, and $P^{\mu}$ is only defined along the path followed by the particle.

Now, to perform a measurement of the energy of a particle, the particle and the observer must coincide in the same spacetime point. Once both the observer and the particle coincide, then the equation $E=-P_{\mu}U^{\mu}$ is actually a way to write:
$$E(p)=-g_{\mu\nu}(p)U^{\mu}(p)E^{\nu}(p)$$

which is valid at any point in the intersection of the path of an observer with four-velocity $U$ and the path of the particle.

What you say about the Ricci tensor is a little different. The components of the Ricci tensor are also functions of the point $p$ in spacetime $R_{\mu\nu}(p)$, but the value of a function is, in general, different at different spacetime points, so the numerical value of $R_{\mu\nu}(p)$ can be zero in some points, and non-zero at other different points.

The numerical value of $E(p)$ is different at different points $p$, but the expression $E(p)=-g_{\mu\nu}(p)U^{\mu}(p)E^{\nu}(p)$ always applies (if p is the intersection point between the paths of the observer and the particle)

Answer (score 1):

Despite appearances, this is not a proper tensor equation in general spacetimes.  The problem is that the vector $P^{\mu}$ is defined at the location of the particle and the vector $U^{\mu}$ is defined at the position of the observer.  A proper scalar arising from contraction requires the vectors to be defined at the same location in spacetime.  For Minkowski you can still make this work because it is a flat spacetime and parallel transport of the vectors from one position to another is trivial.  In a general, curved spacetime this will break down.